# Mongodump on Arch Linux ARM

Tags: mongodb, archlinux-arm

How could I alternatively dump mongodb, since `pacman` does not ship mongodb-tools with it ?

```
[root@pi2 lib]# mongo
mongo       mongod      mongoperf   mongos      mongosniff 
[root@pi2 lib]# mongodump
-bash: mongodump: command not found
```

Comment: Connect from another machine where you "can" run the tool. You can run over the network, and since MongoDB 3.0 that is the only way to connect to an instance. Backup and restore should be discussed on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) anyway, since it is not really about programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you just install mongodb-tools to get command mongodump, mongorestore, etc